# How to filter a Table row with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting jQuery code to Javascript. And I really need to solve this.

I have text input and a table with lot of rows. Upon entering text I need to filter the table rows and show only the matching content rows in the table.

[image]

The image is wrong one. It's should be show only 2.55 version in the table. Note that the jQuery code is working fine. Please see the jQuery code.

```
$('#release-filter').keyup(function() {
  var $rows = $('.table-release tr');
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      console.log(text);
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
})
```

So for I achieved only to get the values. And I can't able to construct the filter function.

```
const releaseFilter = document.querySelector('#release-filter')

releaseFilter.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table-release tr');
  const enteredKey = event.target.value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  const filteredRows = Array.prototype.filter.call(rows, function(enteredKey){return enteredKey}) // I need help here

})
```

I can provide table structure if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code. Hope this will help you.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="release-filter" />
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table-release">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20px">1</td>
    <td style="width:50px">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20px">2</td>
    <td style="width:50px">check</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
const releaseFilter = document.querySelector('#release-filter')
releaseFilter.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table-release tr');
  const enteredKey = event.target.value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  const filteredRows = Array.prototype.filter.call(rows,
    function(row) {
      var text = row.innerText.trim();
      if (text.indexOf(enteredKey) == -1) {
        row.style.display = "none";
        return true;
      } else
        row.style.display = "block";
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay I will try it now. I will let you know

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you so much, .